# Do you ever use "being" instead of because

Tags: grammar, participle-phrases

Do you ever use "being" instead of because or since?

is sentence 1 = sentence 2 ?

> 1) because / since I'm clever I can solve difficult problems.
>
> 2) being clever I can solve difficult problems.

Comment: It's grammatical but it does not "equal" since or because.

Comment: I just said it was not.

Comment: So what does it mean :being clever I can solve difficult problems.

Comment: Being clever, he can solve the problems=is not used in every speech that much. Though it can be. It describes the person, but what comes next is not necessarily a result of it as with since and because. What comes next arises from that characteristic rather than as a result.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that your two examples do mean the same thing, so if it helps you to think of it that way, in this example, you can. But it might be dangerous to do so, because you will run into many situations where an introductory participial phrase *does not* mean "because" at all. For example:

> Being upset, she wandered the beach for several hours.

You could still interpret this as "because," but there's no true causality. Being upset didn't cause her to wander the beach. It's not necessarily even *why* she chose to wander the beach. What we know is that she was upset *while* she was wandering the beach. That may be splitting fine hairs in meaning, though. It's easier to see why "because" doesn't always work if you use verbs other than "to be" as the participle:

> Groaning in frustration, Ellen began cleaning up again.

Anyway, if you're struggling to understand the basics of participles and participial phrases, here is one source with a reasonably good explanation: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/627/02/.

Also, now that you know to look for "participle" or "participle phrase," you should be able to find more information about this subject than you may ever have wanted to know, even if you only search in this community. We have tags for "participles" and "participle phrases."

Answer (score 0):

No. "*Because*" means "you are" (always), while "*being*" means "doing" (or "trying").

> 1) Because / since I'm clever I can solve difficult problems.
>
> 2) Being clever I can solve difficult problems.

Try a different equivalent example:

1) Because / since I'm stupid I poked my eye out. It was an expected outcome.

2) Being stupid I poked my eye out. It was an unexpected outcome.